# Do dietitians 'teach'? And confusion between present perfect vs past simple

Tags: vocabulary, present-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

Is the given sentence correct grammatically and semantically?

> *A consulting dietitian by profession, Tina has enjoyed teaching
>   young children about healthy eating habits for over a decade.*

I feel the use of present perfect tense with the phrase 'for over a decade' in the same sentence is not justified. I feel the correct verb form to be used is 'enjoyed'.

Is the use of the noun, 'teaching' correct there? Does a dietitian teach? And can the use of the present perfect form of the verb be justified?

Comment: The present perfect is fine - pretty much *required*, in a context like this. And of course you can teach people about healthy eating habits.

Comment: 1. *Does a dietitian teach?* is not a question of language, and by the way, well yes, dieticians do. 2. Why do you think the verb form is not justified?

Comment: Unless a question is well formed with clear and complete argument, it may get closed.

Comment: @ divya: Questions like this should be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Assuming Tina is *still* teaching, you ***need*** Present Perfect. If she no longer teaches, it's Simple Past. That's all there is to it. Have a look at [What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/) on ELL, and if anything remains unclear, please ask further questions there.

Comment: @Kris: Paraphrasing *very* slightly, it would be quite possible (and truthful) to say [A retired Church of England priest, Ronald Pearse is one of those who does not think of God as being an independent being.](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk/393479.stm). It doesn't seem *necessary* to me that the initial clause should imply anything about the statement that follows anyway. Tina could be an astronaut by profession, teaching kids about healthy eating in her spare time.

Comment: Many of them actually preach :)

Comment: This question is being subjected to a rollback war. This indicates there is real confusion about what is being asked and how to ask it. Question should be closed until the confusion is addressed by the original poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a dietitian teach?

Not necessarily, but there's no rule to say they can't, and they would hopefully be better at teaching about diet than other people.

And that is what the clause "A consulting dietitian by profession" adds to the sentence; it informs the next clause by stating something about the fact that she was teaching about healthy eating.

> Is the use of the noun, 'teaching' correct there?

Well, more strictly it's a gerund, and it's necessary because in using a transitive sense of the verb *to enjoy* here we need a word that can act as a noun to be it's object. Compare with the incorrect:

> *Tina has enjoyed teach young children…
>
> *Tina has enjoyed taught young children…

These don't work precisely because we don't have an object that is a noun or a form that can act as a noun, as a gerund can.

> And can the use of the present perfect form of the verb be justified?

Assuming that what it says is what is intended, then yes.

One of its uses is to state that something has happened over a period from some point in the past up until the present or very close to the present.

Combined with the following "…for over a decade", this tells us that at some point over a decade ago, she started teaching children about healthy eating habits, and enjoyed it, and has continued to do so up until the present day.